# How to change and improve a select_tag in a rails form so that it returns several values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord

I'm new to programming and I'm having a problem with a complex form(for me) for creating a `Remission` object. This remission has_many `Units`. I have a working form version for this but I want to improve it. In my actual version you need to select the units you want in the remission by selecting them via a checkbox from the list of all the Units (Unit.all). It works fine, but the problem is that the Units are created in batch so there are several copies of each Unit type. What I am trying to do now is to show only each different type of Unit. Each unit type has an Unique `product_code` so I mange to do this via:

```
@units = Unit.where(sold:false).group(:product_code)
```

Now my problem is that I want to change the `checkbox_tag` to a `select_tag` that allows me to select a quantity of units of each type to add them to the remission. This select tag should be from 0 to the quantity of units for each unit type. I have a idea for this but I need some fixes that I can't manage to complete:

```
<% @units.each do |unit| %>
  </td>
    <%= select_tag "quantities[]",options_for_select(0..Unit.where(product_code: unit.product_code).count) %> 
  </td>
<% end %>
```

Can some help me fix this in a way that it returns the value of the quantity selected associated with the `product_code` of the Unit type so I can use that info to create the `remission` in the Controller. Any suggestions are welcome as I'm learning.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. It's quite difficult to debug a verbal description of your code. Can you please edit your question and add the relevant sections that you need help with (eg the select box) including any attempts you mad e(even if it's not working) and any errors you got when you tried various approaches. That way we can see exactly what you're trying to do, rather than designing it from scratch ourselves for you. Then we can help you :) note: don't put code in comments (eg here) because the formatting is dreadful... definitely edit your question to add new code :)

Comment: haha - you edited while I was typing :D still - more is good! Are you trying to get them to select an integer quantity?

Comment: Thanks! I'll edit it in while when I return home. Yeah the quantity need to be an integer because its correspond to the number of Unit objects to be added to remission via remission_id in each of the unit objets to be added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build the set of numbers in the drop-down - looks like you might be able to do it just by dropping the `options_for_select` eg:

```
<%= select_tag "quantities", 0..Unit.where(product_code: unit.product_code.count %>
```

but if you use the same field name for all the drop-downs, you'll only get one result returned per form (the last one will overwrite the previous one). So you need to give it a unique field-name using the unit eg

```
<% @units.each do |unit| %>
  <td>
    <%= select_tag "quantities[#{unit.product_code}]", 0..Unit.where(product_code: unit.product_code %>
  </td>
<% end %>
```

Then you will probably get something like this in params:

```
params[:quantities]
=> {'abc123' => 4, 'def456' => 1}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm learning to program by myself and documantion seems a little bit too abstract sometimes.It worked with the code <%= select_tag "quantities[#{unit.product_code}]", options_for_select(0..Unit.where(product_code: unit.product_code).count) %> . I have only one question remaining that I hope you could help me with. Now I get a hash with the codes and the quantity I select, the problem is that it also contains all the values with the  values : 'code' => 0 with the units I left with the 0 for quantity. Is there a quick fix for only getting the ones I change select?

Comment: By the way using the code without the count at the final part produced the error no valid range.

Comment: Does processing the resulting hast with params[:quantities].delete_if {|k,v| v == "0"} makes any sense?

Comment: Yes, if you look at he docs on the select_tag: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag you can see that one of the options is a prompt. If you add a prompt - then it won't pass a value unless somebody changes it from the prompt.

Comment: Hopefully what I've said is enough to help you out, but otherwise with any new errors, you need to ask a new question so you can give me all the details and the code isn't in the comments (where code-formatting is dreadful). it'll be easier to understand that way :) When you do, put the link int he comments here so I can spot it.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I forgot to add the count part - I'll update.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I manage to resolve all my errors. :)